# Monitoring established connections to destination address

Tags: linux, ubuntu

We have suspicious that we have remote access tool in our server, we would like to monitor traffic to and from of destination address. We need to know id of the process. We want to investigate which process is established connections to suspicious source IP address

Comment: Maybe try `netstat -anp` and see if you get anything suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

You can get nethogs

```
sudo apt-get nethogs
```

It will get the traffic usage, PID, and IP.

after that you can do a

```
sudo tcpdump -i ethX host x.x.x.x -w output.pcap
```

Then open up the file in wireshark.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the incoming address or hostname, use lsof and grep

`lsof -i|grep <host>` or `lsof -i|grep <address>`

This will show you the process, PID, and user.